# How to stack or transform the data in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to transform the data from table 1 to table 2 in Excel.

What Excel formula can I use?

[image: Excel table]

Comment: been searching since morning but couldn't find the ans i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Pivot Table. To build the one you want is easy:

- Select your data, including headers
- Go to Insert :-> Pivot Table on the ribbon
- Click OK on the 'Create PivotTable' dialog that appears
- In the next dialog 'PivotTable Fields', place `id` in Rows, `subid` in Columns, and `measure` in Values
- That's it!